Shaking text in textPath svg at the end of the scale animation
UPD: Suddenly the solution has come: one more animation, but for .warning text, which is "parallel" to the scaling of the .wrapper:
.warning text {
  animation: transformTextInSvg 1.5s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes transformTextInSvg {
 to { transform: scale(0.98)  rotateZ(-70deg); }
}

And scaling MUST be a little less than 1. For me scale(0.98) works fine.

Initial question: I've created an animation: that's how it's reproduced. As seen, after the animation ends, the end of the phrase shakes. And if you reload the page quickly, the path is disfigured and is corrected visually that's ugly!
Here is my code:


    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <style>
        body {
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
          margin: 0;
          min-height: 100vh;
          background-color: black;
        }
    
        .wrapper {
          position: relative;
          top: 60px;
          transform: rotateX(90deg) scale(0);
          animation: flight 1.5s ease-in-out forwards;
        }
    
        @keyframes flight {
          to {
            transform: rotateX(50deg) scale(1);
          }
        }
    
        .vinyl {
          position: relative;
          width: 450px;
          height: 450px;
          background-color: red;
          border-radius: 50%;
          animation: rotation 12s linear infinite 2s;
        }
    
        @keyframes rotation {
          from {
            transform: rotateZ(0);
          }
    
          to {
            transform: rotateZ(-360deg);
          }
        }
    
        .warning {
          position: absolute;
          width: 105%;
          height: 105%;
          top: -7px;
          left: -15px;
        }
    
        .warning text {
          font-size: 5px;
          font-weight: 500;
          fill: white;
          transform: rotateZ(-70deg);
          transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        }
      </style>    
    </head>    
    <body>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="vinyl">
          <svg class="warning" width="450" height="450" viewBox="0 0 52.917 52.917" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path id="spiral" style="display:inline;fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none;stroke-width:.0750443"
              d="M42.56 11.55c2.213 1.212 5.243 7.313 5.522 13.066.648 13.413-8.465 22.991-21.887 22.937C15.32 47.509 5.941 38.12 5.893 26.387 6.59 14.11 16.375 6.444 26.743 6.422c9.677-.02 16.072 7.939 16.418 18.383.375 11.326-7.027 18.057-17.144 18.019-8.46-.032-15.738-7.48-15.673-16.628.06-8.392 6.526-15.59 14.464-15.505 8.707.092 13.934 5.951 13.831 13.78-.113 8.678-4.97 13.737-12.805 13.473-5.96-.2-11.075-5.466-10.884-11.947.168-5.69 3.886-10.46 9.25-11.262 4.005-.598 8.664 1.744 8.932 6.845.318 6.044-3.382 11.582-7.49 11.253" />
    
            <text>
              <textPath href="#spiral">Something happened or the requested page not found. Please, reload, try the menu above or go back to the main page.
              </textPath>
            </text>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>    
    </html>



The most interesting thing is that happens in Webkit browsers (Chrome, Edge), but in Firefox everything's fine.
Yes, I tried to resolve the problem myself:

backface-visibility: hidden;
set the exact sizes to svg (no %, but px);
give transform-style: preserve-3d to the containers
but nothing works for me.


I suggest reporting the problem as a Chrome bug given that Firefox doesn't have this issue.

Please add a reproducible example based on the compiled CSS. We can't see the error when SASS mixins are missing. BTW.  Chrome, Edge, brave etc are using Blink not webkit (like Apple Safari, midori or epiphany).

@herrstrietzel, sorry, I'm here not long ago and sometimes don't understand how to articulate a question. Now the example is reproducible with only compiled css

@RobertLongson, hi, it may be a Chrome bug, but is there a workaround? And thanks for my message corrections: English is not my native language :)

Suddenly the solution has come: one more animation, but for .warning text, which is "parallel" to the scaling of the .wrapper - look the update above. Anyway, thanks everybody for the quick reaction and your advices!
